# django login_required decorator outside view

Tags: python, django, view, login-required

I am trying to use `login_required` decorator outside django view. 
I am using this in a function on my utils.

```
@login_required
def somefunc():
    #logic
```

and then I am calling this `somefunc()` in my view

```
class MyView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         my_func = Somefunc()
```

When I do this it says `object has no attribute 'user'`
Whats the issue here ?

Answer (score 1):

`login_required` is looking for a request object as the first argument to the decorated view function. The request object has a `user` attribute, which is then checked to see if the user is actually logged in. You can't wrap an arbitrary function with this decorator and expect it to work exactly the same as with an actual view function.

Comment: What if i send request to my SomeFunc(request)

Comment: That might work. I think that `login_required` will return a HttpResponse if the user is not logged in, so you should handle that somehow. See the source code for how this works: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/contrib/auth/decorators/#login_required

Comment: However, this is a quite roundabout and obscure way of handling it, and could cause unexpected bugs. I recommend just writing an explicit check yourself instead of using `login_required`. You could also check out django-braces, as suggested by @jgadelange.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the `login_required` decorator on the `View`. This can either be achieved by overriding the `dispatch` method.

```
class MyView(View):
    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(MyView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

You could create your own mixins for achieving this or just use [`django-braces`](http://django-braces.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)'s [`LoginRequiredMixin`](http://django-braces.readthedocs.org/en/latest/access.html#loginrequiredmixin).

If you want to have this check in the function it might be better to raise a `PermissionDenied` exception in `somefunc`.

Either way you will need the `request`/`user` in `somefunc`